# Convert Sharepoint Calendar Recurrence Data from xml to string

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-calendar

I am creating actual/exception events for a SharePoint calendar event recurring instance and I want to convert the RecurrenceData field value which is an xml string to a readable form like "Every Monday at 9am" (something SharePoint seem to be able to do internally somehow). How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you want a string representation of the XML or in 'human readable format' (e.g. "Every Monday at 9am") or something else? You've got to give details if you want good answers!

Comment: I want 'human readable format' automatically displayed from xml.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @Ryan When you look at recurring event exception records, you will notice that while the master record contains an xml string in the RecurrenceData field, the exception list item seem to contain the readable version of it (e.g. "Every Monday at 9am") . This mean that SharePoint must have some way to translate the XML to the readable string used when creating exception. I think Ahmed is asking how SharePoint does that, which sadly is the same thing I am still searching for 2 years later